# Matrix identities in two variables

Tags: matrices, matrix-theory

The famous [Amitsur-Levitzki Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amitsur%E2%80%93Levitzki_theorem) states that the algebra $M_n(\mathbb C)$ satisfies no polynomial identity of degree less than $2n$ and it satisfies
$$p(x_1,\dots,x_{2n}) = \sum_{\sigma \in \frak S_{2n} }{\rm sign} (\sigma) \cdot x_{\sigma(1)} \cdots x_{\sigma(2n)},$$
a polynomial in $2n$ non-commuting variables.

> > **Question:** What is the smallest degree of a non-trivial polynomial identity of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ in two variables?

By inserting non-commutative monomials in two variables into the Amitsur-Levitzki polynomial one gets an upper abound of the degree of
$$2n \lceil \log_2(2n) \rceil.$$ Is $O(n \log(n))$ optimal? The question might be approachable for low $n$, but I am more interested in asymptotic properties.

Comment: I believe this is pretty much an unsolved problem. At least it is described as such in various sources on PI-algebras, including books of Formanek (1990) and Drensky-Formanek (2004).